# I'm having problems implementing viewPager with a custom BottomNavigation

Tags: java, android, responsive-design, android-viewpager

Is there any way to implement a `ViewPager` in an already finished application which uses a custom `bottomnavigation`? I've been trying to adapt through some classes I watched about `viewPager`, but it keeps going wrong.

I'm using  ["MeowBottomNavigation"](https://github.com/oneHamidreza/MeowBottomNavigation) in the app and I'm trying to implement a simple `viewPager`, if anyone has any links or knowledge of how to make this implementation, I would be grateful =D

Comment: What did you tried so far. can show your code.

Comment: you can check this [MeowBottomNavigation Github](https://github.com/oneHamidreza/MeowBottomNavigation).

Comment: I've already done my custom buttomnavigation, my problem is implementing the viewPager 2

Comment: You can check this [example of how to implement viewPager 2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/viewpager2-in-android-with-example/)

Answer (score 0):

here [github.com/sazibislam/set_schedule](http://github.com/sazibislam/set_schedule) you can check the code. I already implemented bottom navigation view and view pager with kotlin, mvvm and dagger2. here is the class for custom bottom navigation view. [custom bottom navigation view](https://github.com/sazibislam/set_schedule/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/set/sazib/utils/view)